# Image Rotation Animation in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Upon Taping an image, i want the image to rotate. I checked online but nothing seems helpful.
So how can this be done?
Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I found the solution and it appears to be pretty simple. The following code does the trick of rotation animation of an image:

```
            Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Duration = duration;

            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.Duration = duration;

            sb.Children.Add(da);

            RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, rt);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
            da.To = 360;

            Search.RenderTransform = rt;
            Search.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

            sb.Begin();
```

Comment: With or without an animation?

Comment: Please place your update as a answer and mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I tried that but i can't do this before 8 hours from the time i put the question so waiting till then :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does the trick  rotate an image:

```
            Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Duration = duration;

            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.Duration = duration;

            sb.Children.Add(da);

            RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, rt);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
            da.To = 360;

            Search.RenderTransform = rt;
            Search.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

            sb.Begin();
```